# Cygwin - Shell Scripting (eval and echo)

Tags: shell-script, cygwin

I have the following file f1.txt:

```
A=0    
A=\`expr $A + 1\`
```

and the following script file s1.sh

```
for line in $(cat testfile.txt)
do
   echo "$line"
   # eval $line
done
echo $A
```

When I run the script using "sh s1.sh" I get the following output:

```
A=0    
A=`expr      
$A     
+    
1`
```

I was expecting the output of the echo to be:

```
"A=`expr $A + 1`"
```

1. I'd like to know why echo is putting newlines between the words?
2. As well, when I uncomment the `eval` line I get the following error:

   ```
   s1.sh: eval: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'     
   s1.sh: eval: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
   ```

I'd like to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Echo is putting newlines between words because it's splitting the input at the spaces, not at the newline.
2. This is also why the eval doesn't work - it sees the first word, containing a `'`, and doesn't see the end of the line, which contains the closing `'`

#### Solution:

Change the value of IFS (Internal Field Separator) to not contain spaces or tabs, but just newlines. You do it like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

before you start reading in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `for` loops for this. By default, as explained by @JennyD, your shell will split on whitespace and not keep the entire line. This is not the case if you `read` the file into a `while` loop instead of `cat` and `for`:

```
 $ while read line; do echo "$line"; done < f1.txt;
 A=0
 A=`expr $A + 1`
```

This will also make the `eval` run correctly:

```
$ while read line; do eval "$line"; done < f1.txt; echo "A is $A"
A is 1
```

So, for example:

```
$ cat f1.txt 
A=5    
A=\`expr $A + 1\`
$ while read line; do eval "$line"; done < f1.txt; echo "A is $A"
A is 6
```

Comment: If I change A=0 to A=5, I expected to $A to be 6 but $A is 1. In A=`expr $A + 1`, the $A is always 0. Why?

Comment: @EggHead sounds like you're doing something wrong, it works fine here. See update.

Comment: Yes, I was using eval echo "$line" instead of eval "$line". It works now. Thx!